# Stop the whole ros through C++ code

Tags: ros, c++, shutdown

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Does anyone know is there c++ API that can help to shut down the whole ros instead of a node? What I want to do is I plan to use shell script for automating the simualtion in ros. I use roslaunch command for spawning the environment and drones. And run another c++ file (a node) for controller. However, I do not know how to stop ros when the controling algorithm is finished. If I use ros::shutdown(), I can only shutdown the controller node but the graphic interface is still here. So, does anyone here know any way to shut down the whole ros through c++ code?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270812/stop-the-whole-ros-through-c++-code/) by [jasonwang538@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/30092/jasonwang538@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-09-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you run everything from a single launch file, you can add the `required="true"` attribute to your controller node, which will cause roslaunch to stop all of the other nodes when your controller node exits.

See http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node for a more detailed description of all of the attributes to the `<node>` tag and what they do.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jasonwang538@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/30092/jasonwang538@gmail.com/) on 2017-09-13**:
Thanks, sir. This is exactly what I need. Appreciate that.